# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'

Tags: python, twitter

I have written some basic Python code to try authenticate my credentials on twitter:

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                      consumer_secret='',
                      access_token_key='',
                      access_token_secret='')
```

But I receive the following error message when doing so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\nettest.py", line 3, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have tried variations on this code but they all seem to fall down with the api part of the twitter 1.14.2 that i am using. i have installed this module via pip 3.3 to my python 3.3 directory. when i look in lib>site_packages>twitter i can see that there is a module installed called api. I'm really not sure what is going wrong as this should seemingly be a simple piece of code to run.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a local file named `twitter.py` I bet. What does `print(twitter.__file__)` tell you?

Comment: Or, you are probably mixing packages: the one that [has API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/1.3.1) and the one [that doesn't](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter).

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have run throught this scenario previously and removed any unrelated python files and folders from within my python33 folder or any related subfolders. the above resolves to 'C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\twitter\__init__.py' which is the file where the twitter module unpacked itself to.

Comment: @user3045351: then alecxe's comment is your next port of call; you didn't install the `twitter` package you thought you had.

Comment: @martijnpeters i have installed twitter 1.14.2...the site where i originally got some code from said to use twitter.py, however this is not listed in the directory on pypi.

Answer (score 5):

- simply uninstall twitter `sudo pip uninstall twitter`
- Now install python-twiiter `sudo pip install python-twitter`... and it works..

Answer (score 4):

If you were using the python-twitter You have a local file named twitter.py  Rename it to twitterhelper.py or some other name and it should fix your problem.   This was what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Save your python file with any name other than twitter.py.